# Blow up of cone over quadric surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

If $X\subset \mathbb{P}^4$ is a 3-dimensional quadric hypersurface given by a rank 4 quadratic form (e.g. $X$ is a cone over a smooth quadric $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\cong Q\subset\mathbb{P}^3$), then blowing up at the cone point $p\in X$ resolves the projection $\pi_p: X\dashrightarrow Q$ to express the blowup $Bl_pX\rightarrow Q$ as a $\mathbb{P}^1$ bundle over $Q$.

How do we see that $Bl_pX\cong \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1}(1,1))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a special case of a more general result. If $Y \subset P^n$ is a projective variety and $X \subset P^{n+1}$ is the cone over $Y$ with vertex $p$, then $Bl_p(X) \cong P_Y(O_Y \oplus O_Y(-1))$.

To see this you can construct the maps between both sides by using the universal properties of the projectivization and of the blowup.

Comment: Okay, after thinking about this a little more, I think the fact that we have two sections (the exceptional divisor and a hyperplane section missing the cone point) shows it's the projectivization of the direct sum of two line bundles. To identify the line bundles we compute the normal bundles to the sections. The only tricky one is the normal bundle of the exceptional divisor, but we can use http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132965/normal-bundle-of-an-exceptional-divisor. Is that what you had in mind by "constructing maps"?